# Disable “Try it out” in swaggerUI for specific paths in swagger 2+

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is there a way in swagger 2 spec to disable “Try it out” in swaggerUI for specific paths.
I dont want to disable for all methods and paths, rather a specific method on a path.
Example - POST /files/upload

Comment: What [Swagger UI version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) do you use- 2.x or 3.x? Do you you use Swagger UI directly (e.g. using its `dist` assets or npm modules) or is it bundled with some library/framework?

Comment: I use swagger 2.x. I use it directly. I host the swaggerUI when the webservice starts. Also, we use swagger validator to validate the request.